# can't access to dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a good day everyone..

I have a data frame named Description .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcSvh.png)
I showed from rows using :

> `description.head(5)`

When I run this command, my data appears as I created it.

Whereas when I try to extract values for certain rows or columns, I can't do that, so I don't see any values for the entered condition

```
    age = description.loc[description['subject'] == '50784',['AGE_AT_SCAN']]

    print(age)
```

Output:

> Empty DataFrame
>
> Columns: [AGE_AT_SCAN]
>
> Index: []

Can you help me to solve this problem??

Comment: May be your subject is int type. Try `age = description.loc[description['subject'] == 50784,['AGE_AT_SCAN']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
age = description.loc[description['subject'] == 50784]['AGE_AT_SCAN']
```

This will return a series comprised of index and the value at 'AGE_AT_SCAN'.  if you're just interested in the value you can add the following:

```
age = description.loc[description['subject'] == 50784]['AGE_AT_SCAN'].values[0]
```

This will vectorize the output.

Comment: I used the second solution:                                                                                             age = description.loc[description['subject'] == image_ID]['AGE_AT_SCAN'].values[0]
    sex =description.loc[description['subject'] == image_ID]['SEX'].values[0]                       then I tried to create tensorfolw record as :  feature = {
               'subject': _bytes_feature(subject.encode('utf-8')),
               'subject_age': _int64_feature(age),
               'subject_sex': _int64_feature(sex)}